# Using Fourier Transform to Transform Image into Sound (I don't think it's working)

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, plot, fft

**Backstory**

I started messing with electronics, and realized I need an oscilloscope. I went to buy the oscilloscope (for like $40) online and watched tutorials on how to use them. I stumbled upon a video using the "X-Y" function of the oscilloscope to draw images; I thought that was cool. I tried searching how to do this from scratch and learned you need to convert the image into the frequency domain and some how convert that to an audio signal and send the signal to the two channels on the oscilloscope from the left and right channels from the audio output. So now I am trying to do the image processing part.

**What I Got So Far**

*Choosing an Image*

First thing I did was to create an *nxn* image using some drawing software. I've read online that the total number of pixels of the image should be a power of two. I don't know why, but I created 256x256 pixel images to minimize calculation time. Here is the image I used for this example.

[image]

I kept the image simple, so I can vividly see the symmetry when it is transformed. Therefore, if there is no symmetry, then there must be something wrong.

*The MATLAB Code*

The first thing I did was read the image, convert to gray scale, change data type, and grab the size of the image (for size variability for later use).

```
%Read image
img = imread('tets.jpg');

%Convert image to gray scale
grayImage = rgb2gray(img);

%Incompatability of data type. uint8 type vs double
grayImage = double(grayImage);

%Grab size of image
[nx, ny, nz] = size(grayImage);
```

*The Algorithm*

This is where things get a bit hazy. I am somewhat familiar with the Fourier Transform due to some Mechanical Engineering classes, but the topic was broadly introduced and never really fundamentally part of the course. It was more like, "Hey, check out this thing; but use the Laplace Transformation instead."

So somehow you have to incorporate spatial, amplitude, frequency, and time when doing the calculation. I understand that the spatial coordinates is just the location of each pixel on the image in a matrix or bitmap. I also understand that the amplitude is just the gray scale value from 0-255 of a certain pixel. However, I don't necessarily know how to incorporate frequency and time based on the pixel itself. I think I read somewhere that the frequency increases as the y location of the pixel increases, and the time variable increases with the x location. Here's the [link](http://www.lnse.org/papers/94-VC3007.pdf) (read first part of *Part II*).

So I tried following the formula as well as other formulas online and this is what I got for the MATLAB code.

```
if nx ~= ny 
    error('Image size must be NxN.'); %for some reason
else

    %prepare transformation matrix
    DFT = zeros(nx,ny);

    %compute transformation for each pixel
    for ii = 1:1:nx
        for jj = 1:1:ny
            amplitude = grayImage(ii,jj);  
            DFT(ii,jj) = amplitude * exp(-1i * 2 * pi * ((ii*ii/nx) + (jj*jj/ny)));        
        end
    end

    %plot of complex numbers
    plot(DFT, '*');

    %calculate magnitude and phase
    magnitudeAverage = abs(DFT)/nx;
    phase = angle(DFT);

    %plot magnitudes and phase
    figure;
    plot(magnitudeAverage);
    figure;
    plot(phase);
end
```

This code simply tries to follow this discrete [fourier transform example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkGsMWi_j4Q) that I found on YouTube. After the calculation I plotted the complex numbers in complex domain. This appears to be in polar coordinates; I don't know why. As stated in the video about the Nyquist Limit, I plotted the average magnitude too. As well as the phase angles of the complex numbers. I'll just show you the plots!

**The Plots**

*Complex Numbers*
[image]
This is the complex plot; I believe it's in polar form instead of cartesian, but I don't know. It appears symmetric too.

*Average Amplitude Vs. Sample*
[image]
The vertical axis is amplitude, and the horizontal axis is the sample number. This looks like the deconstruction of the signal, but then again I don't really know what I am looking at.

*Phase Angle Vs. Sample*
[image]
The vertical axis is the phase angle, and the horizontal axis is the sample number. This looks the most promising because it looks like a plot in the frequency domain, but this isn't suppose to be a plot in the frequency domain; rather, its a plot in the sample domain? Again, I don't know what I am looking at.

**I Need Help Understanding**

I need to somehow understand these plots, so I know I am getting the right plot. I believe there may be something very wrong in the algorithm because it doesn't necessarily implement the frequency and time component. So maybe you can tell me how that is done? Or at least guide me?

**TLDR;**

I am trying to convert images into sound files to display on an oscilloscope. I am stuck on the image processing part. I believe there is something wrong with the MATLAB code (check above) because it doesn't necessarily include the frequency and time component of each pixel. I need help with the code and understanding how to interpret the result, so I know the transfromations are correct-ish.